# jquery - sum of all checkbox value * their unique textbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need sum of (every check box value X its textbox value)

```
<input name="33" value="280000" onclick="test(this);" type="checkbox">
<input id="33" style="width:20px;float: left; text-align: center" type="text">
```

example:

```
 fist checkbox value = 20 X its textbox value = 10  
 second checkbox value = 5 X its textbox value = 2  
 my answer = 20*10 + 5*2 = 210 (ok)
```

also i need when checkbox value changes my answer change, without click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const totalBox = document.getElementById("total")

document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]").forEach((input) => input.addEventListener("input", calculate))
document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]").forEach((input) => input.addEventListener("change", calculate))
function calculate() {
  const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]")
  let total = 0
  for (let checkbox of checkboxes) {
   if (checkbox.checked) {
      total += Number(checkbox.value) * Number(document.getElementById(checkbox.name).value)
    }
  }
  totalBox.textContent = total
}
calculate()
```

```html
<input name="33" value="280000" type="checkbox" checked>
<input id="33" value="10" type="text">
<br/>
<input name="34" value="150000" type="checkbox">
<input id="34" value="15" type="text">
<h2>Total: <span id="total"></span></h2>
```

Comment: how can i show result in sth like this?

    `document.getElementById('Totalcost').innerHTML = total + " $";`

Comment: could you please help me how can i use this? 
i copied and pasted this sources in simple html file, and doesn't worked. 
@marzelin

Comment: @AlirezaSabahi here's an example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jLONxb Notice that javascript goes after html content

Answer (score 1):

If they are always grouped by two you can simply take all inputs, multiply every pairs value and add it up:

```
var result = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("input")).reduce(function(result,el,i,arr){
   return result+i%2?el.value*(arr[i-1].checked?arr[i-1].value:0):0;
},0);
```

for shure this can be executed inside an *onchange* handler.

http://jsbin.com/muvigedodu/edit?js

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/yuhpbz47/

```js
var total = 0;
$('button[type="submit"]').click(function(){

 $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
    total += $(this).val() * (parseInt($(this).next().val()) || 0 );
    }
  });
 console.log(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="10" />
<input type="text" />

<br/>

<input type="checkbox" value="20"/>
<input type="text" />

<button type="submit">
Submit
</button>
```

Comment: `function test(item){`  

        `if(item.checked){`

           `total+= parseInt(item.value)*(parseInt($(this).next().val()) || 0 );`
       `}else{`
           `total-= parseInt(item.value)*(parseInt($(this).next().val()) || 0 );`  
        `} `
how can i use this source in this code?

Comment: does it work? i cant work with this:
also i want to show in 
`document.getElementById('Totalcost').innerHTML = total + " $";`

Comment: @AlirezaSabahi ... Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/uedvqo00/1/ .Everything is woking, have a check in the jsFiddle

Comment: thanks, and how can i make it sensitive for checked checkbox. once textbox value changed. answer update

Comment: If you want to do an update on every keypress in textbox then on-click method in input checkbox is not a good idea.

Comment: @AlirezaSabahi ... I have updated the fiddle with all the solution you asked for https://jsfiddle.net/yuhpbz47/2/

Comment: thank you, but i really don't know my <span id="total"></span> doesn't returns the answer

Comment: @AlirezaSabahi .. Here you go with span https://jsfiddle.net/yuhpbz47/3/ . Check the browser console for error & use inspect to check the span is hidden or may be below some other div.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to achieve, when a check box is clicked a value is multiplied by the value of the input check box then for all check box give us the sum right? if so this below code which is well documented should help out with it

Observe the pattern i used to get the multiply value so it can be dynamic
Hope it helps.

```js
$(document).ready(
function(){

/**
* this is used to update our view so you see what we are   * doing currently now
*/
function updateView(value){
$("#view").html(value);
}

$(".sum").click(function(event){
//we get our value to multiply our value with 
var multiply = $(this).attr("multiply"); 
var value = $(this).val();

//we multiply here 
var answer = multiply*value;

//we sum up this value with the sum in the hidden fied if checked else substract

var sumField = $("#sum");

if($(this).is(':checked')){
sumField.val(Number(sumField.val())+answer);
}else{
sumField.val(Number(sumField.val())-answer);
}

//update our view
updateView(sumField.val());
});



} 
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Check boxes 
<br>
1. <input type="checkbox" value="10" multiply="20" class="sum"> value 10, multiply 20 <br>
2. <input type="checkbox" value="5" multiply="10" class="sum"> value 5, multiply 10  <br>
3. <input type="checkbox" value="3" multiply="5" class="sum"> value 3, multiply 5 <br>

<input type="hidden" value="0" id="sum">

value: <div id="view">

</div>
```